# Blank Output using Stash

Tags: expressionengine

I'm finally giving Stash (version 2.3.5 on EE 2.5.3) a go on a project to see if it's as good as everyone says.

I've followed the docs as much as I can and set up the stash at the header of the page as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
{exp:stash:set_list name="homepage"}
    {stash:cf_homepage_main_intro}{cf_homepage_main_intro}{/stash:cf_homepage_main_intro}
    {stash:cf_homepage_strapline}{cf_homepage_strapline}{/stash:cf_homepage_strapline}

    {cf_homepage_contact_info}
        {stash:mx_pinterest}{mx_pinterest}{/stash:mx_pinterest}
        {stash:mx_facebook}{mx_facebook}{/stash:mx_facebook}
        {stash:mx_twitter}{mx_twitter}{/stash:mx_twitter}
        {stash:mx_tel}{mx_tel}{/stash:mx_tel}
        {stash:mx_email}{mx_email}{/stash:mx_email}
        {stash:mx_address}{mx_address}{/stash:mx_address}
    {/cf_homepage_contact_info}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And then in the rest of my template, I'm attempting to call the values as follows:

```
{exp:stash:homepage:mx_tel}
```

However, I get nothing.

If I output the field names directly they work fine, I've also turned on debugging and I can see the point in which stash sets the values, and that all looks fine, however the debugger reports the following:

*Stash: RETRIEVED homepage:mx_email with value*

I'm a little at a loss on where to go from here... Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks,

Carl

Comment: OK - I've made a tweak to it now to use {exp:stash:set} and {exp:stash:get}, but still no luck. {exp:stash:set name="cf_homepage_main_intro"}{cf_homepage_main_intro}{/exp:stash:set} and then {exp:stash:cf_homepage_main_intro}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! I see in your question that you're trying to call the vars from inside the same template. So you're running into a parse order issue. You need to add the `process="end"` parameter to your `exp:stash:get_list` or `exp:stash:get` tags. And read my [article about template partials](http://eeinsider.com/articles/template-partials-using-stash/)!

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I think maybe you've got the syntax mistaken. Try:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="homepage"}
  Telephone: {mx_tel}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Also, if you're only retrieving one item, I'd skip using set_list and just use set for the separate variables. Both things work, but I think it's more intuitive..?

Comment: I'm following the instructions on https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev which show how to do it as above.

Comment: The above answer is correct as far as syntax, even on dev. The shortcut syntax doesn't work for lists. It's not a bad idea to keep using the set_list, though; it allows you to keep things DRYer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Stash's get_list tag pair when using set_list, append_list and prepend_list.

What you are using is a Stash shortcut which is the same as stash:get though, not the same as stash:get_list according to the docs.

Use get_list:

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev#expstashget_list-tag-pair

Not get shortcut:

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev#shortcut-tags (used for set/get)

Also, the shortcut which you are using is actually making use of [context](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev#context--string):

```
{exp:stash:your_context:your_var_name}
```

Note "your_context" in the tag above

Comment: So, I've now changed the logic in the header to following format:

{exp:stash:set name="cf_homepage_main_intro"}{cf_homepage_main_intro}{/exp:stash:set}

and then using {exp:stash:cf_homepage_main_intro} and its still not working.

Comment: I think you should still go with set_list and change your get to a get_list instead; as aelvan mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the I was trying to call the {get} within the same template, so needed the process='end' after the tag.

Also, just for reference - this is what I'm using:

```
{exp:stash:set name="cf_homepage_main_intro"}{cf_homepage_main_intro}{/exp:stash:set}
```

and then to get that back out (with shortcut tag):

```
{exp:stash:cf_homepage_main_intro process='end'}
```

Job Done!

Answer (score 2):

{exp:stash:set_list name="homepage"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage" limit="1" dynamic="no"}

Does it matter that stash is inside the loop, as in parse order stuff, doesn't stash come first?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference either way :(

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the question, rather than a separate "Answer".